# Batch - how to copy file by minimum size and date modification?

Tags: windows, batch-file, batch, windows-command-prompt

I have this simple batch script which copies the newest file in some dir to another place.
I want this script to also ignore all files (in the DIR command section) under 1GB of size.

```
FOR /F "delims=|" %%I IN ('DIR "Y:\DEVL\*.*" /B /A-D') DO SET NewestFile=%%I 

copy "Y:\DEVL\%NewestFile%" "F:\DEVL\%NewestFile%"
```

Any help would be very appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

**Option 1:** If you want to copy the newest file, but only if it's greater than 1GB, just replace your copy command with:

```
robocopy "Y:\DEVL" "F:\DEVL\" "%NewestFile%" /min:1073741824
```

/min:n defines the minimum size in bytes.

**Option 2:** If you want to copy the newest file of all files that are greater than 1GB, it's more complicated.

```
@echo off

Set CopyResult=0
FOR /F "delims=|" %%I IN ('DIR "Y:\DEVL\*.*" /B /O:-d /T:w /A-D') DO Call :DoCopy "%%I"
Goto :EOF

:DoCopy
  IF %CopyResult%==1 Goto :EOF
  set CurrentFile=%1
  robocopy "Y:\DEVL" "F:\DEVL" %CurrentFile% /njs /njh /is /min:107374182
  Set CopyResult=%errorlevel%
```

/min:n defines the minimum size in bytes.

Comment: That will only skip the copying if the file is less than 1gb.  It will not, as I think the OP wants, copy the newest file that IS less than 1gb.

Comment: Glenn: Thanks, I guess you can read the question two ways. I updated my answer.

Comment: ERROR : Invalid Parameter #3 : " /min:1073741824"

And it took the wrong file :) The script now runs over all files, taking the actually newest (after listing all files as newest one after the other) - a 70kb file.

Comment: Hi Zeda, Again I'm not receiving any successful results here. Please try and run your script and see what happens

Comment: About the error. If you remove @ECHO OFF command you'll see the actual cammand that is executed. Can you copy that in a comment for me?

Comment: If it took the wrong file the sorting of the dir command is not correct. I edited the script and included /O:-d (order by date, newest first) and /t:w (date for sorting = date last written, use /t:w if you want the creation date).